# Route request to Tomcat only if file doesn't exist on disk

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I have Apache in front of my Tomcat installation as a reverse proxy. Most URLs are routed to Tomcat by a `JkMount` directive in Apache.

For one URL pattern I'd like Apache to route requests to the Tomcat worker only if a static asset isn't found on the filesystem.

Something roughly like this:

```
RewriteCond /var/www%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond /var/www%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/assets/.*$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://${tomcat-ssl}/$1 [P]  # This syntax is wrong
```

What syntax can I provide for the `RewriteRule` to route the request to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to create an `Alias`, which Apache treats as a synonym for a give path. I created a `RewriteRule` that rewrites the URL to this `Alias` if the file exists. Since the `Alias` doesn't match the `JkMount`, the `JkMount` doesn't handle it. If the file *doesn't* exist, the `RewriteCond` fails, the `RewriteRule` isn't applied, and the request gets passed to Tomcat.

```
Alias /localstaticassets /var/www/assets                                                                                                                                                                                                     
RewriteCond /var/www/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f                                                                                                                                                                                                  
RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*)$ /localstaticassets/$1 [QSA,PT]

JkMount /assets/* tomcat-ssl
```